# FormData append File Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel

I'm using FormData to send image to Laravel API.
When I use this code it does not work:

```
onChange(event: any) {
 const images = event.target.files;
 if (images.length <= 5) {
  Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
    console.log(image);
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image, image.name);

    console.log(formData);

    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/web', formData).subscribe(data =>  {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
 }
 event.target.value = '';
}
```

`console.log(image);` I get `File(651565){}`

`console.log(formData);` I get `FormData {}`

`console.log(data);` I get `{}`

So if you can see, the first works but the after no longer.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

if the 'onChange' function is appended to HTMLInputElement then try this:

```
const images = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
```

**after editing**

I took a deep look into it and it seems like this line is the problem:

```
event.target.value = '';
```

and the reason for that its because here:

```
const images = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
```

you are taking the files as 'Reference Type' so if you change the value as you did here:

```
event.target.value = '';
```

you deleting the files object.

try to do this:

move the 'event.target.value = '';' to subscribe method so only when was a success you can delete them, and also you need to create error function and then remove it when an error occurs.

basically what you doing here is deleting the files only after they were uploaded or error so you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Nothing has changed